# How can I assign a "@html.DropdownlistFor" to a text box. - JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hy Guys!

I tried

```
$("#InputCategory").text($("#ddlCategory").text());
```

but didn't work.

---

The html tags:

`<input type ="text" id="InputCategory"/>` and the MVC helper...

```
@html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Category....)
```

which is converted to `< select id="ddlCategory"/>`

---

What's wrong with my Jquery code?

**Edit:**
Maybe it's another mistake.

Does this function works:

```
$("#ddlCategory").change(function(){
$("#InputCategory").text($("#ddlCategory").text());
});
```

Am I using the wrong event to this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign the value of a select element to a textbox you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

```
$("#ddlCategory").change(function(){
  $("#InputCategory").val($(this).find(":selected").val());
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/ZJN7R/).**

If you want to get the text you can simply call `.text()`

```
$("#ddlCategory").change(function() {
    $("#InputCategory").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Id for the textbox in the html tag. Please set the Id to be InputCategory and try it.

HTH

Comment: I only didn't put here.. but it has an Id. I edited the post.

Comment: Please try this $("#InputCategory").val($("#ddlCategory option:selected").text());

Comment: it almost worked. But it gets all options. It's like if I have: Option 1: Apple. Option 2: Grape. And the result on input will be "Apple Grape".

Comment: That is pretty weird....you are executing that in the change event of Category drop down right? Anyways try this:$("#InputCategory").empty().val($("#ddlCategory option:selected").text());